# Ominous gaps in disk activity

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, resource-monitor, disk-activity

A few times over the past hour, I've had my computer temporarily lock up on me. As CPU and RAM usage seemed okay, I looked at my disk activity in the Resource Monitor.

[image: Ominous-looking disk activity graph]

Having the computer slow down due to large amounts of disk access wouldn't be completely surprising as my computer is currently running multiple things at the same time, most notably Spotify, IntelliJ IDEA, Excel and a quasi-mandatory virus scan.

However, if these charts are correct, the exact opposite is happening. All disk access to the C drive seems to just stop for perhaps 20-40 seconds at a time.

Now, my question is how I should interpret this. Is this normal? Is Resource Monitor perhaps flawed and cannot measure the IO access properly? Should the fact that it seemingly shuts down be seen as a sign of an imminent hard drive failure?

(I just realized that I should probably mention that the C drive is a laptop SSD.)

Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: You may want to run a SMART tool to confirm the hard drive health is OK (or to at least, get an overview of the hard drive)... There are many free ones on the net although I have had good results with Acronis